# Installing a program in its entire default installation program (without being asked anything)?

Tags: apt, postfix

To install programs in Ubuntu I usually do `sudo apt-get install <program_name> -y`.

There are some particular programs I install that ask me **non-password** configuration questions.

For example, after doing `sudo apt-get install postfix -y` I was asked for particular Postfix set of configurations, although the default was just fine to me.

How can one make sure an install that asks non password question won't ask it nothing? Surly, the only reason is to automate a few, particular installation processes.

Note: The solution I seek is per program, not global.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the solution there is global, I'm looking for something per program, something "local".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "per program". The command given in the solution there only installs one package (`sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install package-name`).

Comment: By "per program" I mean that I don't want to change some conf, then install, then change the conf back. I just want to pass some argument that will install the particular package non-interactively, into the `apt-get install` command.

Comment: There's nothing in there that says to change any configuration. It just adds some text into the command you're running, like `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install package-name`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I didn't see a command afterwards. I now understand my traditional way of `sudo apt-get -y install package-name DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is good.

Comment: Be careful, because the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` part has to come just before `apt-get`.